# Linear Algebra operations with ROS

Tags: ros, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create some example nodes that execute linear algebra commands. I wanted to try the TooN library (http://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/toon.html). I was trying to follow what the package `tum_ardrone` has done in regards to this.

1. I downloaded the folder containing the TooN library files and moved it to the the directory `/thirdparty/TooN/include/`.
2. I added the following to my CMakeLists.txt file:

   ## set required libs and headers

   include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/TooN/include )

Based on the file HelperFunctions.h located in `/tum_ardrone/src` I created a simple program to perform basic matrix operations. I will be using these functions later and since I'm not familiar with any library like this one I need to start from the basics. When I execute `rosmake` I get the following error:

```
 /home/pedro/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/controlador_ardrone/src/ejemploalgebralineal.cpp: In member function ‘void LinearAlgebra::InverseMatrix()’:
  /home/pedro/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/controlador_ardrone/src/ejemploalgebralineal.cpp:31:31: error: ‘struct TooN::Matrix<3>’ has no member named ‘inverse’
```

Here is the code I try to compile:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <TooN/TooN.h>
#include <TooN/so3.h>

  using namespace std;
  using namespace TooN;

  struct LinearAlgebra
  {
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    void InverseMatrix(){
        TooN::Matrix<3,3> mat;
        mat = Data(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
        TooN::SO3<> res = mat.inverse();
        std::cout << "m3_4\n" << mat << "\nm3_5\n"<<res  << std::endl;
    }

    void Commands(){
        InverseMatrix();
    }
  };

////////////

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc,argv,"Linear_Algebra_ROS");

  LinearAlgebra linearalgebra;
  ros::Duration wait_time = ros::Duration(3,0);

  while(linearalgebra.n.ok()) {
      wait_time.sleep();
      linearalgebra.Commands();
      ros::spinOnce();
  }
  return 0;
```

Does anybody have experience with this library and/or other libraries that I can use? Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129531/linear-algebra-operations-with-ros/) by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 182 on 2014-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most frequently used linear algebra library within the ROS ecosystem probably is [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/index.html). A usage example can be found in the [Coding a realtime Cartesian controller with Eigen](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Coding%20a%20realtime%20Cartesian%20controller%20with%20Eigen) tutorial. An example of how the setup of package.xml and CMakeLists.txt has to look with catkin can be obtained from the [laser_geometry](https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_geometry) package.

I haven´t tried the TooN library, so cannot comment on that one.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2014-02-15**:
Thanks for your answer! I was reading about the Eigen library and seems to be doing the job. I'm still curious why the authors of tum_ardrone preferred the TooN libraries instead. I want to wait a couple of days before I accept this as an answer. I want to see if someone can help with TooN.